# Boost results by position in multi-valued field

Tags: solr

I have a hierarchical structure like Client->Project->Subproject (it can have n levels). For each leaf (Subproject) I keep a multi-valued ordered field of parents up to the root, so the search can match on both name and parent names.

When someone searches for "pro" I would like the results to show up in the following order: subprojects first, then projects, then clients, as below:

```
<doc>
  <str name="name">Sub**pro**ject1</name>
  <arr name="parentNames">
    <str>Project1</str>
    <str>Client1</str>
  </arr>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="name">Subprj2</name>
  <arr name="parentNames">
    <str>**Pro**ject1</str>
    <str>Client1</str>
  </arr>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="name">Subprj3</name>
  <arr name="parentNames">
    <str>Prj2</str>
    <str>Client **Pro**1</str>
  </arr>
</doc>
```

Boosting the name is simple, but boosting the parentNames applies equally to all entries in the multi-valued field, so entries 2 and 3 will not appear in the order I wanted.

I assume there is no straightforward way to achieve this, but which way would you go? Custom search component or maybe somehow boosting the values at index time?